# Is it possible to use a class template in its member functions?

Tags: c++, templates

My class is size parameterized. In one of its methods I have to create a temporary array, but I don't know how to pass the class's size template to the member function. This is how I tried:

```
#include <array>

template<unsigned int N>
class MyClass{
    std::array<int,N> m_data;
  public:    
    void myFunc(){
        std::array<int,N> tempArray;
    }
};


int main(){
    MyClass<5> obj;
    obj.myFunc();
}
```

**Edit:**
Build log:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C ""C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe" -j6 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile"
"----------Building project:[ hatizsak_konyv - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'E:/progi/c++/CodeLite/Other/algoritmusok/dinamikus_programozas/hatizsak_konyv'
"C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"  -c  "E:/progi/c++/CodeLite/Other/algoritmusok/dinamikus_programozas/hatizsak_konyv/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
E:/progi/c++/CodeLite/Other/algoritmusok/dinamikus_programozas/hatizsak_konyv/main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void MyClass<N>::myFunc() [with unsigned int N = 5u]':
E:/progi/c++/CodeLite/Other/algoritmusok/dinamikus_programozas/hatizsak_konyv/main.cpp:15:16:   required from here
E:/progi/c++/CodeLite/Other/algoritmusok/dinamikus_programozas/hatizsak_konyv/main.cpp:8:27: warning: unused variable 'tempArray' [-Wunused-variable]
         std::array<int,N> tempArray;
                           ^~~~~~~~~
"C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/g++.exe" -o ./Debug/hatizsak_konyv @"hatizsak_konyv.txt" -L.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/progi/c++/CodeLite/Other/algoritmusok/dinamikus_programozas/hatizsak_konyv'
====1 errors, 1 warnings====
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This code does not work, and i can not fix it.

Comment: Template parameters are visible inside method definitions, that code should work fine as it is; what's the problem? What error messages do you get?

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work" ? Compiler error? If yes what is it ?

Comment: @Hamzsé: That's not a question, that's just a complaint. Work harder at asking a question. Take the tour, learn how to ask effective questions.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the build log, just a correct warning about the fact that you are not using that variable.

Comment: The lines before!
"main.cpp:15:16:   required from here"

Comment: it says "1 errors, 1 warnings", but there is no error

Comment: it would be nice from you, if you tried to compile it

Comment: @Hamzsé: the lines before just provide context for that warning. I don't know what CodeLite is smoking, there's no error at all in this build log. I compiled it and [it compiles fine](http://ideone.com/nGmrAb).

Comment: Whoa! Thanks. The problem is really with CodeLite. It _does_ compile if i compile it from the command line. The strange thing is, the problem does only appear when i use the template N inside a member function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template parameters are visible inside methods of the template class; the code is correct.

There's no error at all, nor in the provided code example, nor in the build log. The message in the build log is just a warning (with the lines before providing context for it), which correctly warns you about the fact that that variable isn't used, as per the `-Wall` option provided on the command line. Other than that, the code [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/nGmrAb), both on ideone and on my machine (where it gives you exact same *warning*, not error).

```
[matteo@teolapkubuntu /tmp]$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 stuff.cpp 
stuff.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void MyClass<N>::myFunc() [with unsigned int N = 5u]’:
stuff.cpp:15:16:   required from here
stuff.cpp:8:27: warning: unused variable ‘tempArray’ [-Wunused-variable]
         std::array<int,N> tempArray;
                           ^~~~~~~~~
```

The "1 error" message at the end of the build log is just CodeLite misinterpreting the compiler output; there is [an open bug about it](https://github.com/eranif/codelite/issues/1075), with conditions similar to yours.